# Post Json through API using curl, no results

Tags: php, api, post, curl

I am fairly new to this so hopefully its not something silly i am missing out on. I am trying to create an order for someone using API.

I have searched for hours how to do this on stackoverflow and all the post have been great help. But now I have hit a brick wall. This code does not seem to throw any errors when visiting the PHP page nor does it take the item away from stock on like its meant to.

Am i missing something really simple, also is there a way to check if its working?

```html
<?php

$today = date("D M j Y G:i:s T");
$data = array(
 "order" => [
   "order_number" => "",
          "company_id" => 690094,
          "billing_address_id" => 1018327, 
          "shipping_address_id" => 1018327, 
          "stock_location_id" => 16377,
          "ship_at" => $today,
          "issued_at" => $today, 
          "tax_type" => "exclusive", 
          "payment_status" => "unpaid",
          "fulfillment_status" => "shipped",
          "email" => null,
          "reference_number" => 7784,
          "status" => "fulfilled",
          "order_line_items" => [
              "quantity" => 1, "discount" => null, "price" => 1, 
              "tax_rate_override" => null, "freeform" => false,
              "variant_id" => 6983077
          ],
        ],
);

$url ="https://api.tradegecko.com/orders/";
$str_data = json_encode($data);

function sendPostData($url, $str_data){
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',  
    'Accept: application/json',                                                                                                                               
 'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Bearer 872ed5e72dfc7e4e0adaa7c663cab7d81415078fdbe4f486d085b718c93b3eb3")
    )                                                                       
);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$str_data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);  // Seems like good practice
  return $result;
}

echo sendPostData($url, $str_data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `Authorization` header is not done in the right way. It should be done as in:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',  
    'Accept: application/json',                                                                                                                               
    'Authorization: Bearer 872ed5e72dfc7e4e0adaa7c663cab7d81415078fdbe4f486d085b718c93b3eb3')
);
```

For debugging purposes it is helpful to add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
```

Finally, you should create a new access token for this service since yours is public now.

Comment: Thanks for this! I have changed the access token, that was me being very stupid. 

I get this error now - {"status":"500","error":"Internal Server Error"}, seems very generic, any ideas?